# PyMySQL, MySQL, Python: String formatting

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I can't find a solution to this on SO, so my last choice is to ask this. I ran the code on MySQL and everything seems fine, but when I ran the code in Python, I got an error: `%d format: a number is required, not str`, is this a glitch of PyMySQL? The two `%s` should be the placeholder of `apple` while the `%d`, `%b`, and `%y` should be only used within the SQL command and does not act as the placeholder outside the command.

```
db.query("""SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD
            ('1970-01-01 00:00:00',INTERVAL pubtime SECOND),
            '%d %b %Y') AS pubdate FROM media
            WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST (%s
            IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH (headline) AGAINST (%s
            IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY pubtime DESC LIMIT 5""",
            ('apple', 'apple'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can escape '%' by adding another '%' before it.

```
db.query("""SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD
        ('1970-01-01 00:00:00',INTERVAL pubtime SECOND),
        '%%d %%b %%Y') AS pubdate FROM media
        WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST (%s
        IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH (headline) AGAINST (%s
        IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY pubtime DESC LIMIT 5""",
        ('apple', 'apple'))
```

Comment: While adding two percent symbol, I got an error `(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),\n            '%d %b %Y') AS pubdate FROM media\n            WHERE MATCH (descri' at line 2")`